# After initializing a timer other code never runs

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

Here is a code I use to init timer:

```
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0f 
target:self selector:@selector(tick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 

    NSRunLoop *currentRunLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]; 
    [currentRunLoop run]; 

    int a = 10;
```

After calling "[currentRunLoop run];", "int a = 10;" doesn't perform.(even after calling tick: method by timer)

Why?
Thank you.

Comment: why are you calling `currentRunLoop`?

Comment: because it's NOT main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Run loop run] stops there - it never goes past that line of code it just "loops"

You shouldn't need to create your own run loop usually.

If you want to achieve a timer on a separate thread just use a timer on the main thread and have the target method perform its work on a separate thread

Comment: Thank for answer. Now it works. But I still don't understand why it don't work in my own thread.